# Giving each domain unique IPV6 address for posfix SMTP

Tags: networking, debian, ipv6, smtp, postfix

Today I faced a problem after setting up postfix as my mailserver and sending e-mail to a gmail email, which responded me with the following message:

> Our system has detected
>       that this message does 550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding
>       PTR records and 550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1
>       https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ipv6_authentication_error for more 550

and as it turns out, when mailing through IPv6 reverse DNS is needed for the IPv6 address the mail is sent from, which I thought should be no problem as the dedicated server I ordered came with IPv6 subnet big enough to handle all my domains, which my ifconfig reports to be the following:

inet6 addr: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64 Scope:Global

and after a little research in the IPv6, this means that I have whopping 64 bit range to work with, so I want to try this out simply with binding my postfix server on 'just another address' to confirm that everything works

I set in postfix's main.cf the following property

```
smtp_bind_address6 = xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::3
```

and restarted the mail server and sent another mail, but as it turns out, the mail was still received from the original IPv6 address, xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2 and logs doesn't show any details about this.

Also if I try to telnet into the address ending in ::3, it doesn't answer. I don't have any iptables rules set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and after a little research in the IPv6, this
>   means that I have whopping 64 bit range to
>   work with

No, it doesn't. It means your system has one address in a /64 subnet. If your provider told you you can use the whole /64 then you can, but you still have to configure those addresses on your interface.

This is the same as with IPv4. Having address 192.0.2.1/24 (or 192.0.2.1/255.255.255.0 if you prefer the old notation) just means you have one address in a /24 subnet. This doesn't magically change in IPv6.

You can only use the addresses that are configured on your server.

Comment: Oh, the explanations on the site must have been a little misleading, after adding the ip to the interface it started working as intended! Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a lot of misinformation out there, which is why I stated as plainly as possible that it is wrong, so hopefully I will save a few people from being misled ;)